# XQuery: comparing datetimes with milliseconds

Tags: python, xpath, xquery, berkeley-db-xml

I have a validation module in Python that executes an XQuery on an XML document to check if any `<Start>` times come after `<End>` times, and return the count of them. The query is as follows:

```
    for $d at $count in ./ty:Detections/Detection
        where $d/Start > $d/End
        return $count
```

Now this works fine and good for all cases except when milliseconds are appended to an End time but **not** a Start time, e.g.:

```
        <Start>2009-02-23T02:53:14Z</Start>
        <End>2009-02-23T02:53:14.226Z</End>
```

This always returns True, even though clearly 14 is less than 14.22.
If I add a single decimal place to the `<Start>` time here, it works -- but is there any better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably there is no schema binding in effect for the `Start` and `End` elements. In that case the query is doing an xs:untypedAtomic comparison, which effectively compares the string values, where `"Z"` compares greater than `"."`.

What you want is an xs:dateTime comparison, so you should compare the element values after casting them to that type. The query thus should look like:

```
    for $d at $count in ./ty:Detections/Detection
    where xs:dateTime($d/Start) > xs:dateTime($d/End)
    return $count
```

Comment: Gunther == gentleman + scholar, this solves it sir!
however, I chaged to `xs:dateTime` capital T :)

Comment: Thanks. That's right, there is a capital `T` in `xs:dateTime` ;-)